# SP2010 Crawled Properties

Tags: 2010, user-profile-property, managed-property, crawled-property

I'm creating user profile properties and making them searchable. But now, I need to set a last property of the Crawled Property. So how can I check the "Include values for this property in the search index" on a Crawled Property **WITH C#**??? It's located under the "Mappings to managed properties" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. After you link the mapped property to the crawled property, you need to update the crawled property:

```
crawledProperty.IsMappedToContents = true;
crawledProperty.Update();
```

And then it should work...